# Problems with ACTION_TIME_TICK in Android

Tags: java, android, android-service

My Phone doesn't vibrate every minute. Here is my code:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;

public class vibrateNow extends Service {
static IntentFilter s_intentFilter;
static {
    s_intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    s_intentFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_TIME_TICK);
}
BroadcastReceiver yourReceiver;

public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    this.yourReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            showSuccessfulBroadcast();
        }
    };
    // Registers the receiver so that your service will listen for broadcasts
    vibrateNow.this.registerReceiver(vibrateNow.this.yourReceiver, s_intentFilter);
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}   

private void showSuccessfulBroadcast() {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

    // Vibrate for 300 milliseconds
    v.vibrate(300);

}
}
```

By the way in the way: I registered in Android Manifest the `android.permission.VIBRATE` permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have the permission in the wrong place.

Or, you may not be starting the service.

Or, you are starting the service, but are stopping it, and Android is getting rid of your empty process before the next tick arrives.

Or, you are testing on the emulator, which does not have a vibration motor.

Or, you are testing on a device that does not have a vibration motor.

There may be other problems, but those should get you started.

Comment: I think that I might not started my service, how could I start or end it?

Comment: @alexvii: To start a service, you call `startService()`. To stop a service, you call `stopService()`, or the service calls `stopSelf()`.

Comment: but like you could see in my answer I already tested it. what are Im doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please help me? I dont get it.